# Xcode 9.4.1 Code Coverage on 'guard' statement

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

Having a bit of trouble getting 100% code coverage after implementing Unit Tests in my Swift 4 project in Xcode 9.4.1.

For some reason, when I have a `guard` statement in a failable initializer, my code coverage always seems to say `0` for it, even though I *do* test for it.

[image]

[I've created a demo project so you can see for yourselves.](https://gitlab.com/dansinclair25/guard-test-example)

How do I get Xcode to show that this code is covered with unit tests?

I'm relatively new to the whole Unit Testing side of things, so if there's any advice you can give, or any other places to check out to read up on it, I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

/Dan

Comment: Are you testing with an empty dictionary? In other words, are you testing the negative case where the guard statement executes and returns nil?

Comment: Can you show your code coverage screen?

Comment: First of all you should get rid of all your implicitly unwrapped optionals. Don't post screen shots post your actual code.

Comment: @Guven even with an empty dictionary I get the same issue

Comment: @MuhammadHassan you can see the number of times the line has been covered in the column to the right of the line. The red area containing a `0`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you explain further about "getting rid of implicitly unwrapped optionals"? Regarding posting of the code, there's a GitLab link to an example project which shows the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't answer the question entirely, but if you replace `class` with `struct` (migrating from reference space to value space), you'll hit the 100% test coverage.

WEIRD!